Capacitor in Isolation Amplifier
Reading this article and looking at the schematic inherent to Phase Current Sense, I don't understand why there are two 22-ohm resistors and the 4700pF capacitor in the input of TLP7829. Perhaps to filter the current measured by the shunt resistor?


That's a low pass filter with a corner around 770KHz.  Unless your sensor signal is in that range, I'd assume it's just to filter environmental noise from the input signal.  It will also help to a limited extent with differential ESD, although for high protection levels you should have an ESD Zener directly across the inputs (physically as well as schematically).  You may not need high performance ESD protection at this point in the circuit, depending on the physical configuration.

Thank you for your reply! With "Unless your sensor signal is in that range" do you mean whether the TLP7829 op amp band needs input signals below that frequency? Because by "sensor" I don't understand what you are referring to, since there is no sensor in the schematic

@KaleM You get to chose the cutoff frequency by changing the capacitor values.  You should choose the cutoff frequency as needed for your source signal ("sensor").

I mean the IUN and IUP signals.  I guessed they were from an external sensor.  In normal use, will your input signal have relevant content above 770KHz?

They come from a 1mΩ shunt resistor along the line coming from the inverter and going to the motor
